# Changed lof and lot breaks due to hyperref package

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

For my thesis I want to change my LOF and LOT to be divided into seperate chapters like:

> ```
> Chapter 1
>
> figure 1.1
> figure 1.2
>
> Chapter 2
> ```

etc.

For this I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}


\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{linktoc= all, hidelinks}


\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \providebool{newchap}

\makeatletter
\let\oldcaption\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[2][\shortcaption]{%
\def\shortcaption{#2}
\ifbool{newchap}{%
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{%
        \nameref{cpt:\thechapter} \vspace{10pt}}{}}    
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{%
        \nameref{cpt:\thechapter} \vspace{10pt}}{}}   
        }{}
    \global\boolfalse{newchap}%
\oldcaption[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\saved@chapter}{}
\let\saved@chapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\setcounter{lofdepth}{0}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\setcounter{lofdepth}{0}}
\@ifstar {\saved@chapter*}{\@dblarg\my@chapter}}
\newcommand*{\my@chapter}[2][]{%
\saved@chapter[#1]{#2}
\label{cpt:\arabic{chapter}}%
\global\setbool{newchap}{true}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\setcounter{lofdepth}{1}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\setcounter{lofdepth}{1}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
    \addtocontents{lof}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
    \addtocontents{lof}{\hrule}
    \hrule
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
    \addtocontents{lot}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
    \addtocontents{lot}{\hrule}
    \hrule
\newpage

\chapter{Example}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{2cm}{2cm}
    \caption{Example}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This code works perfectly as long as I dont enable `\usepackage{hyperref}`. If `hyperref` is enabled the first entry in the lof/lot breaks. I figured that it breaks because both my code and the `hyperref` package use `\renewcommand{\chapter}`. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Your example doesn't compile without error. Didn't you test it?